# Having trouble setting x-axis endpoints in proc univariate

Tags: sas, format, x-axis

My code is as follows:

```
data mydata;
    call streaminit(1234);
    do binary = 0 to 1;
        do i = 1 to 1000;
            var = rand('integer', 0, 150);
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;

proc univariate data=mydata noprint;
where var le 100;
class binary;
histogram var/overlay endpoints=0 to 100;
run;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me exactly as I would like it to. It shows 110 on the x-axis and the bar for 100 is to right of it. Is there a way to format the x-axis so that it doesn't show 110 on the x-axis?

I tried changing my code with different restrictions to see if that works. It works when I restrict my data to 80 or 90. X-axis does cutoff at 80 or 90 respectively. It is the 100 that seems to extend the x-axis.

Edit:

```
proc sgplot data=mydata;
histogram var/group=binary;
xaxis values=(0 to 100 by 10);
run;
```

Edit2:
Richard's suggestion to use midpoints, instead of endpoints, in proc univariate worked too. Thank you Sir!

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue on 9.4M8. It shows 0-100 for me with no other points after it. I also set the goptions to 1920x1080 and didn't see any extra values. Which version of SAS are you on? I have added some sample data so others can test it out, too.

Comment: Basically, it is about how to split bins. Try to use `where var lt 100` to replace `where var le 100` and see what happen.

Comment: Stu, thanks for adding the sample data. Var is a rate variable that cannot exceed 100. In my data, I do have some datapoints where var=100. I am using SAS studio. A colleague suggested to use sgplot which solved my problem.

Comment: whymath, I tried 'where var lt 100' but I actually have some datapoints where var=100 that should be displayed as well. Upon a colleague's suggestion, I used sgplot and was able to resolve my problem.

Comment: Why **not** use `midpoints = 0 to 100` instead of `endpoints=`?